# md5 encryption in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I'm using md5 encryption for my company salary data.
That page should only be viewed when user enter correct password. iam storing that encrypted password in database.
while retrieving iam comparing the encrypted password.
Is there any way i can use that password as key?

i want to achieve following

1. If the user is saving the salary data, this password hash will encrypt the data
2. If the user is viewing salary info, this password should be used to decrypt the data

or do i have to use some algorithm like Triple Des?

Comment: I do see a huge security failure in that you can never change the password. If you do the encrypted salary data will not decrypt unless you decrypt with old then reencrypt. And if the password is lost then the salary data is gone forever.

Comment: ok..tht means i have to use a diff algorithm to encrypt my salary data

Comment: md5 is a digest mechanism, it is not an encryption scheme. You want to derive a secret key from the password

Comment: yess with that key i will encrypt remaining data... but then again if i use tht key as encryption.. i have to store in database that key... else how iam going to retrieve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a (reversible) [encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption), not a (one-way) [hash algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is a one way encryption, use Triple DES to encrypt the data and MD5 to encrypt the password.  Here is what I use:

```
public static string Crypt(this string data, string password, bool encrypt)
{
    var u8Salt = new byte[] { 0x26, 0x19, 0x81, 0x4E, 0xA0, 0x6D, 0x95, 0x34, 0x26, 0x75, 0x64, 0x05, 0xF6 };
    var iPass = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, u8Salt);
    var iAlg = Aes.Create();
    iAlg.Key = iPass.GetBytes(32);
    iAlg.IV = iPass.GetBytes(16);
    var iTrans = (encrypt) ? iAlg.CreateEncryptor() : iAlg.CreateDecryptor();
    var iMem = new MemoryStream();
    var iCrypt = new CryptoStream(iMem, iTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    var u8Data = encrypt ? Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data) : Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    try
    {
        iCrypt.Write(u8Data, 0, u8Data.Length);
        iCrypt.Close();
        return encrypt ? Convert.ToBase64String(iMem.ToArray()) : Encoding.Unicode.GetString(iMem.ToArray());
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use SHA2 (for the passwords). http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/GoodbyeMD5.aspx

Comment: He's using asp.net, it's part of the framework. There are also Javascript implementations found easily, e.g. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html

Comment: Cyberdrew what u doing in this code.. how u assigning key ipass.getbytes(32) what value is stored in this, yes iam using c#

Comment: This is an extension method I am using to just encrypt or decrypt string data, I pass the password in as a string but it is SHA1 encrypted.

Comment: Please stop using the word "encryption" when you mean "hash".